# Undefined argument error from fminunc function

Tags: octave

I am trying to use the fminunc with a function that is defined in an external file. The document I was studying shows an example with an inline function definition and it works. I tried to move the function to another file and I couldn't get it running. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
>> inlinetest = @(x) x(1)^2 - 3*x(1);
>> fminunc(inlinetest, [5])
ans =  1.5000
>> mytest(5)
ans =  10
>> fminunc(mytest, [5])
error: 'x' undefined near line 2 column 7
error: called from
mytest at line 2 column 5
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
>>

#mytest.m contents
function r = mytest(x)
  r = x(1)^2 - 3*x(1);
endfunction;
```

Comment: Try fminunc(@mytest....

Comment: It worked. Thank you!